# find_system returns objects that are not subsystems in simulink?

Tags: block, simulink, subsystem

When I use  `find_system(gcs,'BlockType','SubSystem')` it returns things that are not subsystems (AFAIK)

In my case the things that are called

> subsys L1 -x

and

> SubsysX L2 - z

are subsystems, but the names are just for debugging purpose, so I can't use the names to match.

Why is `[1x51 char]` and `Sine` and `RealisesUID` appearing?

I only want the subsystems showing up in the Model Browser tree.

```
'test_simulinkmodel/RealisesUID'
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 1'
[1x51 char]
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 1/Sine'
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 1/Subsys1 L2 - 1'
[1x71 char]
[1x68 char]
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 2'
[1x51 char]
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 2/Sine'
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 2/Subsys2 L2 - 1'
[1x71 char]
[1x68 char]
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 3'
[1x51 char]
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 3/Sine'
'test_simulinkmodel/subsys L1 - 3/Subsys3 L2 - 1'
[1x71 char]
[1x68 char]
```

EDIT:
They show up in the model browswer if i select include library links and include systems with mask parameters. However, the default of find_system is 'FollowLinks' 'off' and 'LookUnderMasks' doesn't say. However, even if i provide explicit off and none, they still return the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add LinkStatus parameter to find_system to look for only your own sub-systems and not the ones from libraries. `find_system(gcs,'BlockType','SubSystem','LinkStatus','none')`. The same way you can also add 'Mask' with 'on' or 'off' values to filter based on whether the block has a mask on it.

Is "Sine" a sub-system from your own library? Sine wave block from Simulink library would not show up if you search for 'BlockType' of 'SubSystem'.

Comment: Thank you, LinkStatus does not show up in the documentation for find_system, where did you find it? I'm not sure about Sine, seems to be a Function Block. I'm no simulink developer so I'm not that familiar with any terminology.

Comment: RealisesUID still show up, but it seems like its some a subsystem with a openFcn with a link, hopefully I will manage anyway.

Comment: For 'p*','v*' values mentioned in the doc for find_system you can specify any of the block parameters. The table in the doc lists only constraints ('c*' values).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `Sine` block *is* a subsystem if you were to look under the mask, you would probably find an S-function. You can maybe specify a '`SearchDepth`' argument to `find_system` or set '`LookUnderMasks`' to '`none`' (assuming your actual subsystems `subsys L1 -x` and `SubsysX L2 - z` aren't masked).

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html

Comment: I tried LookUnderMasks to none, but it didn't change the result

Comment: Sine is of Blocktype Reference, but still appears

Comment: Sorry, ran out of ideas. You may want to try and contact MathWorks technical support if your license is under maintenance (does not apply for Student licenses)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get all subsystems within subsystems as a result. As suggested by am304 you can limit the search by using `SearchDepth`option, but I usually find it easier to use `Parent` to limit the level of search. In your case

```
find_system(gcs,'Parent', 'test_simulinkmodel', 'BlockType', 'SubSystem');
```

Comment: I want all subsystems, but not the ones which show up when i select ``include library links`` and ``include systems with mask parameters.``  The problem is that those limitations using parameters does not seem to work